# Google cloud storage favicon for PDF File

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, favicon

I have some pdf files hosted on Google Cloud Storage. These files are public and I open them using their public link.

Is there a way I can customize the favicon shown by the browser when I view those PDF?

Can I put a custom Favicon for my bucket?

See screenshot to see which icon I mean, is the Icon shown in the browser Tab, this is chrome:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this is not possible.  When this kind of features are not available, the best is to open a Feature Request (FR) in the Public Issue Tracker of GCP. Before doing so, please make sure that there are no other existing feature requests similar to yours.

Here's an existing [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/169787367).

I would recommend you to ["star"](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue) it to ensure that you receive updates about it. You can also [adjust notification](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/set-notification-preferences) settings by clicking the gear icon in the top right corner and selecting settings.

The [more "stars" in the issue](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests), the most probability to be implemented the feature request. Also, adding this kind of needs makes the GCP Engineering team to have a better visibility of the real/currently needs of the users.